# findViewById returns null for EditText passing values from one class to another class by using functions

Tags: java, android

`findViewById` returns `null` for `EditText` passing values from one class to another class

```
public void HandleSearchButtonValue(int START_INDEX,int places,String featurea){
    try {
        EditText locationEdit=(EditText)findViewById(places);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(locationEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
        String locationAddress =locationEdit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: what is places parameter?

Comment: share code section from where HandleSearchButtonValue() method is called.

Comment: If I am thinking right then, are you passing `places` from another activity? If so then obviously you would get NPE because that `EditText` is in different activity unless you are using same xml in both of them.

Comment: `findViewById` Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in `onCreate(Bundle)`.


Try adding a breakpoint in the code to see the value being passed through into the 'places' parameter and check to see if there is a corresponding value

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` returns the first child view matching the ID.

If you are calling it in an `Activity`, the `android.R.id.content` View (the one you set with `setContentView`) is used as parent, so only views are returned which are in the current Layout.

Please provide more information about the caller and the holding class of this method for further help.